# python ElementTree.tostring(tree) failed but ElementTree.tostring(tree.getroot()) OK, cannot picture the difference

Tags: python, elementtree

I don't understand the failure i add with my code sample below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
with open('sheet_short.xml','r') as f:
   tree = ET.parse(f)
#
# some processing
#
xml_str = ET.tostring(tree)
```

The code is failing with error message

```
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

Searching a bit I ended on a link stating I should use getroot so I replace my last line with

```
xml_str = ET.tostring(tree.getroot())
```

and now it's OK but I'm not sure why it was failing originally.

is it because `parse` returns an ElemenTree object while `tostring` requires an element object?

Thanks for your precious feedbacks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

ET.tostring requires a single xml element, whereas you were passing it the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

They are not objects of the same class. `tree` is a `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` object, while `tree.getroot()` is a `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`. And `ElementTree.toString` requires an `Element` parameter (not an `ElementTree`)

On the other side, `tree` has a `write` method:

```
out = io.BytesIO()
tree.write(out)
xml_str = out.getvalue().decode()
```